# How to capture intent on stock launcher shortcut without root

Tags: applications, home-screen-shortcuts, intents

My device is running MIUI on top of Android 12. I'm using the dual apps feature baked into the rom and there are two shortcut for each of the apps (main and dual apps).
[image: screenshot showing the two shortcuts]

When I'm using stock launcher, the shortcut works as intended, where main WhatsApp shortcut (without the yellow icon in the bottom-left) launches the main WhatsApp and vice versa. However, when using third-party launcher, both of those shortcuts have the same behaviour:
[image: prompt]
without clear way of choosing a default.

I have searched the dual apps setting in my rom to no avail.

I tried to create a shortcut with Shortcut Maker, using this setting
[image: shortcut maker main whatsapp]

that shortcut can launch the main WhatsApp without throwing a prompt so I'm guessing there is a way to specify which WhatsApp I want to launch using the settings provided in the Shortcut Maker.

What I'm asking is a way to capture or know the setting of the shortcut in stock launcher that directly launches the dual WhatsApp so I can implement that in Shortcut Maker.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I'm using Niagara launcher and Shortcut Maker.

Clone Whatsapp and Shortcut Maker, then create shortcut for each apps from Shortcut Maker respectively (for main, create from main Shortcut Maker). Add the shortcut to home page.

Shortcut created from main Shortcut Maker will launch Whatsapp (main) and shortcut created from dual Shortcut Maker will launch Whatsapp (dual).